# What's a placeholder in R programming?

Tags: r

Can someone explain what a placeholder is and how to use it in R programming?

Comment: Sorry, this needs *way* more context to be understandable.

Comment: It's a new way of referring to the data in the LHS of the pipe operator in the RHS of a pipe. It was introduced in R 4.2.0. See [`help('|>')`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/pipeOp.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pipe operator was introduced in R 4.1.
The placeholder `_` is a new way of referring to the data in the LHS of the pipe operator in the RHS of a pipe. It was introduced in R 4.2.0 and

- The placeholder refers to the data set in the LHS of a pipe instruction;
- can only be used in the RHS of a pipe instruction;
- can only be used with a named argument;
- can only be used once;
- it's not needed if it is the first argument of the RHS function, only as a placeholder for a 2nd, 3rd, etc argument.

See [`help('|>')`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/pipeOp.html) and this [r-devel thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2022-April/081636.html).

### Example:

```r
mtcars |> row.names() |> grep("Merc", x = _)
#> [1]  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>